# Poor map resolution when saving go.Scattermapbox() in plotly for python

Tags: save, mapbox, plotly-python, save-image, image-resolution

I have created a map with an overlay of markers and labels using plotly's scattermapbox utility in python. When I try to save the image as a .png file, the resolution of the map is terrible no matter what I set `scale` to in the `fig.write_image()` logic. Below is a code sample and the output image. You can see how the labels are distorted enough where I cannot read them. How can I save a higher resolution (i.e., less fuzzy) map?

Code snippet you can run after inputting a mapbox token:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

mapboxtoken = **PLACE YOUR MAPBOX TOKEN HERE**

data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {
        "latitude": {
            0: 41.61848543654998,
            1: 41.60974217360418,
            2: 41.606083341611374,
            3: 41.61506423238307,
            4: 41.61777932615252,
        },
        "longitude": {
            0: -76.55182449910664,
            1: -76.54734344553233,
            2: -76.56747692210295,
            3: -76.56001621241725,
            4: -76.56078604424849,
        },
        "well_name": {
            0: "MCCONNELL - 2H",
            1: "MCCONNELL - 5H",
            2: "DRISCOLL - 2H",
            3: "ROCKS - 5H",
            4: "ROCKS - 2H",
        },
    }
)

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scattermapbox(
        lat=data.latitude,
        lon=data.longitude,
        name="Nearest Neighbors",
        mode="markers+text",
        text=data.well_name,
        marker=go.scattermapbox.Marker(
            size=8, color="rgb(108, 115, 110)", opacity=1
        ),
        textposition="bottom center",
        textfont=dict(family="sans serif", size=5, color="crimson"),
        hoverinfo="text",
    )
)

mean_lat = data["latitude"].mean()
mean_lon = data["longitude"].mean()

fig.update_layout(
    autosize=True,
    hovermode="closest",
    margin=go.layout.Margin(
        l=0,  # left margin
        r=0,  # right margin
        b=0,  # bottom margin
        t=0,  # top margin
    ),
    mapbox=dict(
        accesstoken=mapboxtoken,
        zoom=13.5,
        center=dict(lat=mean_lat, lon=mean_lon),
    ),
    legend=dict(orientation="h", yanchor="bottom", y=1.02, xanchor="right", x=1),
    showlegend=True,
)

fig.write_image("AFE_map.png", scale=6)
```

My output image is the following. Clearly, it is fuzzy. I even tried bumping scale up to 15, no luck.

[image: fuzzy output image]